# How to refer to "this" in abstract Java class?

Tags: java, this, abstract-class

Is it possible in Java to use `this` inside a method of an abstract class, but as an instance of the subclass at hand, not just of the abstract class?

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass <MyImplementingClass extends MyAbstractClass> {

    public abstract MyImplementingClass self();
}
```

which I overwrite in every subclass I with

```
class MyImplementingClass extends MyAbstractClass<MyImplementingClass> {

    @Override public MyImplementingClass self() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

but I wonder if there are more elegant methods to do this. In particular, one that doesn't require every subclass to overwrite a routine like `self()`.

Comment: A syntax error ? Can you show the code that isn't accepted by your compiler ?

Comment: The issue here I believe is that your `self()` method returns `MyImplementingClass` and not `MyAbstractClass`. You should return a `MyAbstractClass`, the *dynamic type* of the returned object will be the relevant one. I also do not follow why wouldn't you just use `this`? It returns the object itself, with the correct *dynamic type*, regardless of where it is called. You can cast it if you need to

Comment: Very good point amit. It seems that is indeed the problem.

Comment: If you can post the above as an answer, I can accept it and close the topic.

Comment: "... as an instance of the subclass at hand, not just of the abstract class?" That's what `this` already is. It is always dynamically the actual type, not the type of the currently enclosing class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here I believe is that your `self()` method returns `MyImplementingClass` and not `MyAbstractClass`.

You should return a `MyAbstractClass`, the *dynamic type* of the returned object will be the relevant one.

I also do not follow why wouldn't you just use `this`? It returns the object itself, with the correct *dynamic type*, regardless of where it is called. You can cast it if you need to

Answer (score 1):

When overriding methods in Java, you can override the return type to be a subclass of the original type. This code is completely valid:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {

    public MyAbstractClass self() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And the concrete class:

```
class MyImplementingClass extends MyAbstractClass {

    @Override
    public MyImplementingClass self() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is also why you can override `clone()` to return an exact type instead of just `Object`:

```
public class SomeCloneable implements Cloneable {

    @Override
    public SomeCloneable clone() {
        return new SomeCloneable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you can return `newInstance()` of a class to behave like that

```
@Override public MyImplementingClass self() {
    return MyImplementingClass.newInstance();
}
```